# How to change keyboard layout when screen automatically locked?

Tags: unity, lock-screen

I'm still using unity7 as my desktop environment. My problem is sometimes when screen locked automatically I can't change keyboard layout using dropdown menu neither shortcut (alt+shift). It seems [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1226969).

Question is How can I change keyboard layout to english when screen is locked. Because my password is written in english. Is there Any workaround?

Setup is ubuntu 18.04 amd64 + ubuntu-unity-desktop installed.

[image: lock_screen_photo]

Comment: please edit your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using

Comment: @Graham ubuntu information added